# AlarmManager firing when app closed in Oreo and higher

Tags: android, android-service, alarmmanager, android-broadcastreceiver

When using `AlarmManager` in Android 7.1 (Lollipop) and lower and closing the App, `PendingIntent`s with `Service`s are executed as well as those with `BroadcastReceiver`s. In Android 8 (Oreo) and later, only BroadcastReceivers are executed when the App is closed.

Here is an example:

*Activity*

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        long currentTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (long i = currentTimeMillis; i < currentTimeMillis + 60000; i += 10000) {
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TestService.class);
            PendingIntent servicePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), (int) i, serviceIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

            Intent receiverIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TestReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent receiverPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), (int) i, receiverIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, i, servicePendingIntent);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, i, receiverPendingIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

*Service*

```
public class TestService extends IntentService {
    public TestService() {
        super("TestService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
        System.out.println("Service");
    }
}
```

*Receiver*

```
public class TestReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        System.out.println("Receiver");
    }
}
```

*Manifest*

```
<service android:name=".TestService" />
<receiver android:name=".TestReceiver" />
```

When executing this on Lollipop, everything behaves as expected:

```
I/System.out: Receiver
I/System.out: Service
I/System.out: Receiver
I/System.out: Service
I/System.out: Receiver
I/System.out: Service
*App closed here*
I/System.out: Receiver
I/System.out: Service
I/System.out: Service
I/System.out: Receiver
I/System.out: Receiver
I/System.out: Service
```

Whereas on Oreo, this happens:

```
I/System.out: Service
I/System.out: Receiver
I/System.out: Service
I/System.out: Receiver
*App closed here*
I/System.out: Receiver
I/System.out: Receiver
I/System.out: Receiver
I/System.out: Receiver
```

Why does `AlarmManager` using `Service`s behave differently in Oreo than earlier?

Answer (score 1):

Android Oreo limits the ability to create background services. See [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background) for more info. You will have to code around it, using JobIntentService or the like.